# Evaluate Array against object in Javascript for tablr

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Use case:

I need to be able to evaluate a key, value pair, or multiple key, value pairs, against an array and return results based on whether or not the items in the array also appear as keys in the pair(s). The use case is that I have a table that returns volume and weight results based on whether or not a value exists in two separate JSON fields. I've gotten the JSON into the array and pair that I need, but am now stuck because when I try to run an if statement it evaluates true for both cases and I need to separate the cases. Here is an example of the arr and obj I need to evaluate:

```
var arr = ['25GalTub', '50GalTub']
var obj = {25GalTub: "3.5"}
```

For this example, in my table I need to be able to multiply the number of times each arr item appears in the JSON by either it's corresponding value in the object (In this case 3.5 for the 25GalTub) or an arbitrary number if the arr item doesn't appear in the object (in this case let's say 10 for the 50GalTub). Let's say each item appears 5 times in the JSON so my table would need to be like the following:

```
Type        Count      Volume      Total Volume
25GalTub     5          3.5          17.5
50GalTub     5          10           50
```

The issue I keep running into, as mentioned above, is that when I try to evaluate arr and obj and then push to an array to use for the table, whatever if statement I have as last returns true for all. Here's an example (please ignore the other elements in the push statement, those all work fine and are just there to demonstrate how I am building elements of the table):

```
for (let a of arr) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            if (key == a) {
            var m = value
            }
            if (key !== a) {
            var m = 10
            }
        }
    }
}

table.push({
    containerType: vaType,
    wasteType: wasteType,
    **vol: m,**
    wgt: w
})
```

The above returns the following table

```
Type        Count      Volume      Total Volume
25GalTub     5          10           50
50GalTub     5          10           50
```

If I remove the second if statement then I get the following:

```
for (let a of arr) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            if (key == a) {
            var m = value
            }
        }
    }
}

table.push({
    containerType: vaType,
    wasteType: wasteType,
    **vol: m,**
    wgt: w
})

Type        Count      Volume      Total Volume
25GalTub     5          3.5          17.5
50GalTub     5          3.5          17.5
```

I understand what's happening I guess. Both if statements return true because the item 25GalTub in arr matches the key 25GalTub and the item 50GalTub doesn't match so whatever if statement comes last is evaluated as true, and the table displays the result.

What I can't figure out is how to essentially say "Evaluate every item in the arr and return true for those that match and false for those that don't." I have a rather long function that takes everything from multiple "table" arrays and stuffs it all into the final table doing a bunch of math, it's just the m variable that I can't seem to crack for some reason. This is probably something fundamental that I am overlooking, so all answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you are looping over the array *and* the obj:

```
for (let a of arr) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            if (key == a) {
            var m = value
            }
            if (key !== a) {
            var m = 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whichever item comes last in your second `for` loop decides the value of m.

You don't need to loop over obj, you can just fetch the value from the object or fall back to your default:

```
for (let a of arr) {
        var m = obj[a] || 10;
       // push this into your table
 }
```

Comment: While this makes perfect sense and answers the original question, I don't think I can use it. I am using a reduce function later on that's sort of similar to this. I've updated the tables in the original question to better reflect what I need to be able to produce. It's the volume column that is the issue. Hopefully that makes sense. There's a lot being done to the "table" array created in the push function (there's actually 4 push functions) but copying all of it into the question wouldn't really make sense without context.

Comment: Getting the correct m value to push to the table array is where I am having the issue. I may have misunderstood your answer a little, but I don't think I can actually generate the arr you have created, I am stuck with ['25GalTub', '50GalTub'] because I am essentially taking one of the json fields that is unrelated to obj, parsing it, and getting the resulting arr

Comment: have updated... now it returns a more complex object: `{'25GalTub':{ count: 5, totalVolume: 17.5, volme: 3.5 }` - does that help?

Comment: I don't think so unfortunately. Again, I am stuck with trying to check arr =  ['25GalTub', '50GalTub'] against obj = {'25GalTub': '3.5'} to find value m, I can't really alter arr. I'm using reduce later on to get the counts but I still need m to push to the table array as either the value in obj (if the string exists in both arr and as a key in obj) or the arbitrary number (if the string only exists in arr) to be evaluated later. Again, apologies is that is a little confusing.

Comment: Oh man I thought that would do it! One wrench. If I have another key value pair in the object it is still evaluating only against the first value. for example: if obj = {'25GalTub': '3.5', '50GalTub': '5'} the volume column is only returning the result for the count of each array item * 3.5. If I console.log(m) I get both values but for some reason it's only pushing the single value to the table array.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct because with the info I have given, and if you put the push statement inside the for...let statement, it does produce the right table object. It didn't quite solve my problem because I have something else going on in the code that this can't solve, but that's on me. Thank you so much for your help!